# How do you buffer requests using the in memory queue with ServiceStack?

Tags: servicestack

Running SS 4.0.54 at the moment and what I want to accomplish is to provide clients a service where by they can send one way HTTP requests.

The service itself is simple. For the message, open a DB connection and save some value.

What I don't want to have happen is I get a flood of requests within a minute and have to open up a 1000 connections to the DB.

Ideally the client would send their requests over HTTP and fill the queue. SS would then every X milliseconds or if MAX number of messages have been queued, send them to the service.

This way we don't have messages queued up for too long, and we only process X number of messages at a time.

I've looked through http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging but something isn't clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The `InMemoryTransientMessageService` doesn't buffer, it processes the message as soon as it receives it. You'd need to use one of the other [MQ Servers](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging) to have the requests published to dedicated queues in the configured MQ Broker which are then processed serially outside the context of the HTTP Request, the concurrency of which can be controlled using the [threadCount when registering the handler](http://docs.servicestack.net/rabbit-mq#allocating-multiple-threads-for-specific-operations).

When you have a MQ Server registered, any requests [sent to using the SendOneWay API](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#oneway-http-requests-are-published-to-mq-then-executed) (or [/oneway pre-defined route](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes)) are automatically published to the configured MQ Server.